# Cargar varias fotos por medio de un array PHP y MYSQL No funciona

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de cargar unas fotos por medio de PHP y MYSQL, estoy enviando por medio de un for las imagenes desde un formulario, al recibirlas es donde imagino que está mi error, cualquier ayuda la agradezco.

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="addphoto_<?php echo $pid; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <center><h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Product</h4></center>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <?php
                    $a=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from product left join category on category.categoryid=product.categoryid left join supplier on supplier.userid=product.supplierid where productid='$pid'");
                    $b=mysqli_fetch_array($a);
                ?>
                <div style="height:10px;"></div>
                <form role="form" method="POST" action="addphoto.php<?php echo '?id='.$pid; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        <?php
                        for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
                            print '<div style="height:10px;"></div>                 
                            <div class="form-group input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:120px;">Photo:</span> 
                            <input type="file" style="width:400px;" class="form-control" name="image">
                            </div>';
                        }
                        ?> 
                   <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Add Photo</button>
                </form>
            </div>

            </div>

            </div>

    </div>
```

y este sería el addphoto.php

```
<?php
include('session.php');
function addphoto (array $fileInfo = PATHINFO($_FILES["image"]["name"])){
    $result = array();
}
$id=$_POST['id'];

while (array =! empty($_FILES["image"]["name"])){

    if ($fileInfo['extension'] == "jpg" OR $fileInfo['extension'] == "png") {
        $newFilename = $fileInfo['filename'] . "_" . time() . "." . $fileInfo['extension'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "../upload/" . $newFilename);
        $location = "upload/" . $newFilename;
    }
    else{
        $location="";
        ?>
            <script>
                window.alert('Photo not added. Please upload JPG or PNG photo only!');
            </script>
        <?php
    }

        mysqli_query($conn,"insert into carousel (productid,photo) values ('$id','$location')");
?>
    <script>
        window.alert('Product added successfully!');
        window.history.back();
    </script>
<?php
```

?>

```
}
```

me salta este error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\FCH-master\POS\admin\addphoto.php on line 3

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Para empezar, no puedes utilizar *array* como nombre de una función, ya que es una palabra reservada. Después de que subas las fotos, puede que te salgo otro error, algo así como "No se puede escribir en el directorio X" eso es por permisos de la carpeta destino. Prueba cambiando el nombre primero a la función

Comment: voy a corregir eso amigo, muchas gracias

Comment: me salta este otro error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\FCH-master\POS\admin\addphoto.php on line 3

Comment: Es por lo mismo, del array, ¿Quién es array? no puedes utilizar una palabra reservada por el lenguaje como declaración de variable, es decir, el nombre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declaré en el formulario el input como array "archivos[]"
lo mando por url

y en addphoto.php no trabajo

```
<?php
    include('session.php');

    $id=$_GET['id'];

    //Como el elemento es un arreglos utilizamos foreach para extraer todos los valores
    foreach($_FILES["archivo"]['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
    {
        //Validamos que el archivo exista
        if($_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$key]) {
            $filename = $_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$key]; //Obtenemos el nombre original del archivo
            $source = $_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"][$key]; //Obtenemos un nombre temporal del archivo

            $directorio = 'upload'; //Declaramos un  variable con la ruta donde guardaremos los archivos

            //Validamos si la ruta de destino existe, en caso de no existir la creamos
            if(!file_exists($directorio)){
                mkdir($directorio, 0777) or die("No se puede crear el directorio de extracci&oacute;n");    
            }

            $dir=opendir($directorio); //Abrimos el directorio de destino
            $target_path = $directorio.'/'.$filename; //Indicamos la ruta de destino, así como el nombre del archivo

            //Movemos y validamos que el archivo se haya cargado correctamente
            //El primer campo es el origen y el segundo el destino
            if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target_path)) { 
                echo "El archivo $filename se ha almacenado en forma exitosa.<br>";
                } else {    
                echo "Ha ocurrido un error, por favor inténtelo de nuevo.<br>";
            }
            closedir($dir); //Cerramos el directorio de destino


             mysqli_query($conn,"call GuardarImagen('$id','$target_path')"); 
             $pid=mysqli_insert_id($conn);


        }
    }
    ?>
    <script>
            window.alert('Product added successfully!');
            window.history.back();
        </script>

?>
```